# TextBox bound to ObservableCollection not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, observablecollection

I have a textbox bound to an observablecollection, and when I update the element (via a drag and drop which fires an event which is handled in the view file) the textbox does not update its value. However, the data is added to the observable collection on the drop and if I do a refresh of the data (by actually selecting a different item in a listbox and switching back to the current record) the data appears.

I have read: http://updatecontrols.net/doc/tips/common_mistakes_observablecollection and no I don't believe I'm overwriting the collection!

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=ImageGalleryFilenames, Converter={StaticResource ListToStringWithPipeConverter}}" Height="41" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Button Height="25" Margin="0 2" AllowDrop="True" Drop="HandleGalleryImagesDrop">
        <TextBlock Text="Drop Image Files Here"></TextBlock>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

This is my event code for handling the drop in the view file for the user control.

```
    private void HandleGalleryImagesDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {
            var filenames = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);

            foreach (var fn in filenames)
            {
                this.vm.CurrentSelectedProduct.ImageGalleryFilenames.Add(fn);
            }
        }
    }
```

Shouldn't the fact that I'm adding to the collection be enough to update the textbox that's bound to the observablecollection or am I missing something blindingly obvious?

Comment: Is a property changed event fired for the *ImageGalleryFilenames* ? After you handle the drag-drop..

Comment: I believe you are missing the RaisePropertyChanged("ImageGalleryFilenames");

Comment: It's because adding to the collection does not fire the `PropertyChanged` event, it fires the `CollectionChanged` event. Just call property changed for `ImageGalleryFilenames` and that should be enough.

Comment: It won't work even with raising a PropertyChanged event, because the list instance doesn't change, and therefore the change notification will silently be ignored by the binding target. On the other hand the Text property does not listen to CollectionChanged events, so updating the ObservableCollection will also be ignored. It's the wrong approach. Either replace the entire collection, or add a string property (with change notification) to your view model and bind to that.

Comment: I guess a temporary solution is just to assign a new ObservableCollection to the variable to trigger the notify property in the setter. However, as per the link in my question, I'm not actually overwriting in the setter for the observable collection, but just clearing it and adding the items from the value into the current collection.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, there is no way the `TextBox` knows that the collection which is the bound to the `Text` has been updated. Since the `Text` property does not listen to `CollectionChanged` events, so updating the `ObservableCollection` will also be ignored as pointed out by @Clemens .

In your ViewModel, this is one way to do it.

```
    private ObservableCollection<ImageGalleryFilename> _imageGalleryFilenames;
    public ObservableCollection<ImageGalleryFilename> ImageGalleryFilenames
    {
        get
        {
            return _imageGalleryFilenames;
        }
        set
        {
            _imageGalleryFilenames= value;
            if (_imageGalleryFilenames!= null)
            {
                _imageGalleryFilenames.CollectionChanged += _imageGalleryFilenames_CollectionChanged;
            }
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ImageGalleryFilenames");
        }
    }

    private void _imageGalleryFilenames_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        NotifyPropertyChanged("ImageGalleryFilenames");
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```